# "Have trust in" vs. "have trust for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, collocation

What is the appropriate preposition for the following sentence?

> - Is having **trust in** your employer important to you?
> - Is having **trust for** your employer important to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Trust', being a general feeling rather than a single abstract object, would be followed by "in".

Words like 'propensity', on the other hand, are singular abstract nouns, as in: "He has a propensity for gardening."

Answer (score 3):

The expression 'trust for' changes the meaning. There the word *trust* is taken to mean:

> "...property interest held by one person for the benefit of another" - See [Merriam-Webster trust entry 3a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trust)